# Is there a way to get last login timestamp in React auth0 sdk?

Tags: reactjs, auth0

We are using auth0 for authentication in our react app. There is a requirement from the product that we have to show the last login date and time. Is there a way to get that information from auth0?

Answer (score 1):

There’s a field `last_login` in the auth0 user profile as documented in https://auth0.com/docs/users/user-profiles/user-profile-structure
Once the user is logged in, you can retrieve its profile if you want to access the profile per user session.

If however you want to use the auth0 management API to retrieve any user’s login time stamp (without a user session) the check out https://auth0.com/docs/users/user-search/retrieve-users-with-get-users-endpoint

Comment: Tried this in Vue 3 with a user logged in via Google and it was undefined.

Comment: the discussed approach probably only work for auth0's built-in user database, but not for external auth0 social login providers like google.